# Dynamically created EditText appearing in emulator, but not appearing on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

In the app I'm working on, the user will select an exercise from a drop-down box. Depending on what is selected, EditText boxes should appear for user input. In the emulator, this is the case. However when the app is installed on a physical device, the EditText boxes do not appear.

I've looked around online, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

**On Emulator**

[The boxes which should appear when "Walking" is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFWQ.png)

[The boxes which should appear when "Shoulder Press" is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgAMQ.png)

**On Device**

[The boxes not appearing when "Walking" is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ05T.jpg)

[The boxes not appearing when "Shoulder Press" is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsQ4d.jpg)

**Content of the xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="347dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/workoutDate"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/exerciseSpinner"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:text="@string/workout_select"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/workoutLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/workout_add"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="497dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="177dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/workoutLinearLayoutList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="375dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="288dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="665dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="140dp"
    android:paddingTop="650dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Relevant sections of Java file**

```
    final ExerciseDatabaseHelper EDH = new ExerciseDatabaseHelper( context );

    final int ident = new Random().nextInt(1001);

    final EditText textInput1 = new EditText(this);
    final EditText textInput2 = new EditText(this);
    final EditText textInput3 = new EditText(this);
    final EditText textInput4 = new EditText(this);
    final CheckBox customSet = new CheckBox(this);
    final Spinner setsSpinner = new Spinner(this);


    List<String> ExList = EDH.getAllExercises();

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ExList );
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    sp1.setAdapter( dataAdapter );

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition( i );
            updateDisplay( item.toString(),
                    EDH,
                    textInput1,
                    textInput2,
                    textInput3,
                    textInput4,
                    customSet,
                    setsSpinner
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            //nothing
        }
    });

private void updateDisplay( final String exercise,
                            final ExerciseDatabaseHelper EDH,
                            final EditText tx1,
                            final EditText tx2,
                            final EditText tx3,
                            final EditText tx4,
                            final CheckBox ch1,
                            final Spinner sp1
                            )
{
    String typeName = EDH.getExerciseType( exercise );

    LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.workoutLinearLayout);

    List<String> setList = EDH.getSets();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, setList );
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    sp1.setAdapter( dataAdapter );

    ch1.setText( "Custom set" );

    if( typeName.equals( "Distance" ) )// == "Distance" )
    {
        LL.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        LL.addView(tx1);
        LL.addView(tx2);
        LL.addView(tx3);
        LL.addView(tx4);
        tx1.setHint( "Distance" );
        tx2.setHint( "Mins" );
        tx3.setHint( "Secs" );
        tx4.setHint( "Calories" );
    }
    else if( typeName.equals( "Weight" ) )// == "Weight" )
    {
        LL.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        LL.addView(tx1);
        LL.addView(sp1);
        LL.addView( ch1 );
        tx1.setHint( "Weight" );
    }

}
```